# How to solve the recurrence $T(n) = T(\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor) + \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor + 1$ , for $n \geq1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, recursion

I need to find the closed form for the recurrence 
$T(n) = T(\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor) + \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor + 1$

When trying to solve it, I end up with this series 
$\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor + \lfloor\log(\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor)\rfloor + \lfloor\log(\lfloor\log(\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor)\rfloor)\rfloor + .... + 1$
 and I cant solve it further.

where $n\geq 1$. 
For more background context, I need to find the number of bits used to encode a natural number N, using elias-omega encoding, which, if I am correct, should be given by this formula.

Comment: Your problem needs more conditions in it.  Maybe $n \ge 1$ or something?

Comment: @GEdgar, ah yes, that is the case, I'll add it right now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: So with enough logs, $\lfloor\log(\lfloor\log(\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor)\rfloor)\rfloor$ will be $0$ and you stop.  So it is a finite series, not an infinite series.

Comment: @GEdgar, yes, but I am still stumped with finding a formula for the sum of that series, while it is true that it will be a finite series, I need a closed form for the series. So that I can calculate the sum in O(1) time

Comment: Do you need an exact formula (unlikely) or would something like this be enough $$\log n < T(n) < 3\log(n)\quad\text{for } n>10$$

Comment: @GEdgar, I need an exact formula because I need to find the difference between T(x) and T(y) for two natural numbers, x and y

Comment: For practical purposes $T()$ values should be pretty small.  Would your $x,y$ be small enough that you can just compute a table that includes them?

Comment: @antkam, while that is certainly true, it would be better if I can get a closed form for the recursion. But yes, if it turns out that its not possible, then I shall go with the lookup method.